# To find the number of syllables in a word

Tags: python, nltk

I need to find out the number of syllables in a word from the English language using NLTK. This is the code I have so far:

```
import curses 
from curses.ascii import isdigit 
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import cmudict 
d = cmudict.dict() 
def nsyl(word): 
   return [len(list(y for y in x if isdigit(y[-1]))) for x in d[word.lower()]] 

>>> nsyl(arithmetic)
```

After the function call, I get a Name Error saying arithmetic is not defined. 
Can someone help me figure out the error in the code?

Answer (score 17):

you need to put quotes around the word 'arithmetic'